# Opening multiple files in pandas - some of which are 'owner' files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, import

I am trying to open multiple files with pandas into a dataframe.

Only files with a prefix ~$ show an error of

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x15Microso'
```

Here is two of my list of filepaths:

```
bulk_uploads /~$0730-0731.xlsx',
bulk_uploads /0701-0702.xlsx'
```

The one without the prefix opens perfectly fine, and I am not sure why the other one throws an error.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'bulk_uploads ' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 1)
    df['Date'] = str(filename)[:-4]
    li.append(df)

# frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Is there either a way to chance any files that have this prefix to lose it, or another way around it?

It looks like they are files which I have previously opened (I have no files currently open)

Comment: Are you sure that they are not temporary files by any chance?

Comment: You are right, it looks like they are. Whats the best way of avoiding an error in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re

path = 'bulk_uploads ' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

li = []
special=re.compile('$~')  #####add more special characters if any

for filename in all_files:
   if special.search(filename):
      os.remove(filename)
   else:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 1)
        df['Date'] = str(filename)[:-4]
        li.append(df)
```

Can you give this a try and see if it works fine?
It seems that your folder is having temporary files..